# AL:Go! command not found

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-al

I just installed the AL extension in VS Code, and am trying to run the Al:Go! command, however it produces an error and indicates that the command 'al:go!' is not found.

When I open the command palette and begin to type in the command, it offers auto complete which makes me believe the command is available but for some reason not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you kindly.

Comment: Are you running the command inside an `AL` Project? I am not familiar with that, but it looks vscode is looking for several JSON files needed to run the project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-get-started#json-file-settings

Comment: I do not believe so, I was following instructions from Microsoft Learn and it indicated that all I had to do was install the extension and run al:go! in the command palette. I'll check out the docs you just provided, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I uninstalled the extension and then installed again. This time in the popup dialaog box instead of Install, I selected Trust the provider and it installed successfully. This time I was able to see AL:GO! command.